# How to show empty message in datatable, If no data found in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I am using this code

```
<table class="table table-striped b-t b-b patient-search-table"
ui-jp="dataTable" ui-option='{"emptyTable": "My Custom Message On
Empty Table"}'>
<tr><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
<td class="text-capitalize">{{user.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

So, how to show empty message in datatable, If no data found in angularjs.

Comment: Try `<div ng-hide="users.length">No Data Found</div>`

Comment: Please specify, exactly where should I put your suggested code line ?

Comment: You can put it after the table.

Comment: @jcubic Thanks its working without `ui-option`. thanks a lot

Comment: @jcubic : can you please put your comment as an ans so that this question has accepted ans. Otherwise people will come to ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-hide and check it array is not empty

```
<div ng-hide="users.length">No Data Found</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

ng-if to check for length of users:

```
<table class="table table-striped b-t b-b patient-search-table"
ui-jp="dataTable" ui-option='{"emptyTable": "My Custom Message On
Empty Table"}' ng-if="users.length > 0">
<tr><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" >
<td class="text-capitalize">{{user.name}}</td>
</tr>
<div ng-if="users.length == 0">My Custom Message On Empty table</div>
```

Comment: your suggested `ng-if` and my `ui-option` both will work or just your .thanks.

Comment: `<div ng-hide="users.length">No Data Found</div>` it's working for me Thanks